# 503 Error when Trying to Connect with FTP, It Was Working Last 3 Years with No Changes Made

Tags: authentication, ftp

So all of a sudden certain users when trying to FTP get the `503` error.

Here is the full error when I try logging in as a user:

> Response: 530-User cannot log in, home directory inaccessible.
>
> Response:  Win32 error:   Access is denied.
>
> Response:  Error details: File system denied the access.
>
> Response: 530 End
>
> Error:    Critical error: Could not connect to server

The really odd thing is some users can login and others no, all settings the same and this has been working for years.

Windows server 2008 r2

I have setup user isolation settings and like I said there have been no issues up till yesterday where a handful of users can't login.

Any help would be great, i have looked at all related posts here and nothing has worked.

Anonymous authentication was turned on and off, didn't change.

Reset all accounts and nothing, delete accounts and created new ones linked to the new virtual `dir` and still can't login.

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please move your question to [su] (delete here, re-post there). It's [off-topic here](//stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0):

so i was able to find a work around, in the security tab under the folder for the certain users i allowed everyone access along with the user. it works but not ideal.